# Using Hadoop in command prompt

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

Guys I need Spark on my Windows So I installed winutils.exe and now my spark works perfectly.But If   I try to run hadoop using command prompt it throws me an error like this

```
'hadoop' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But before using winutils.exe and setting it as my path , I was able to use hadoop normally.
Can you guys let me know how to rectify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error suggests you don't have the Hadoop bin folder in your PATH anymore.

You can always use `C:\path\to\hadoop.exe`